# Generic Category Sidebar in Carrington Wordpress Theme Framework

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, carrington

I have a site with a bunch of categories.  On each category archive
page, I'd like to show the category description in the sidebar.

I know I can create a sidebar for each category in sidebar/:

```
cat-category1.php
cat-category2.php
```

But that seems to be a bit overkill.

Is there a way to have a
'generic category archive sidebar,' -- one sidebar template file that just pulls in the current category description?

What do I name this file so that carrington
knows to apply this particular sidebar to all the category archive
pages (and not the top-level page, where I show the site description).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thanks to Kai Pan on the Carrington Users mailing list for telling me to RTFM](http://groups.google.com/group/carrington-framework/browse_thread/thread/8d41d893cb9dee00)...

> Hey Fitzgerald,
>
> Did you read the readme document in
>   the sidebar directory? To do what
>   you're describing, just make a
>   "category.php" file in the sidebar
>   folder. You can also make an
>   "archive.php" file too since category
>   listings are usually archives as well.